# git: splitting merge into a few commits

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-merge

I've made a `git merge --squash other_branch` (I've used squash as I use git to work on a svn repo).

Now I've tones of (reasonable) conflicts and I need to go thru it very carefully.

I'm trying to came up with some smart way of working with all this mess and maybe share some work with other guys.

What came to my mind is to divide this merge into a few commits.
I'd like to commit some atom changes as soon as they look ok, they make sense and are compileable.

However I'm not quite sure how can I achieve this. 
I'd have to stage ready files, then `git stash` all others to see if staged ones are compiling, then `git commit` and finally `git stash pop` to continue work with rest of files.

Git however does not allow me to stash unmerged paths.

I cannot find any ready recepies on google. It looks like eveyone does `git merge` at once.

Anyone has some idea or did such merge already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are merging to a branch `target`.

You could commit the result of the merge in a temporary branch, including its conflicts:

```
A---B - target
    \---C - tmp
```

and checkout in smaller chunks the files to work on for your next merge commit:

```
$ git checkout target
$ git checkout tmp -- conflicting_file
```

Then work on the conflicts in `conflicting_file`, and commit it with conflict resolution in your `target` branch:

```
A---B---D - target
    \---C - tmp
```

Then check out the next conflicting file(s) from `tmp` again, go on until you've got all conflicts resolved.

Comment: This has only one disadvantage: after staging conflicting files, git does no more recognise them as files with conflicts and `mergetool`s dosn't work as good as they did ;)

Comment: Does `grep -r <<<<<` help? (I suppose you meant after commit conflicting files to `tmp`, rather than "staging".)

Comment: It's not a problem to find conflict in file for me, I just meant that after commit to `tmp` git no longer marks conflicted files correctly: it treats <<<< and >>>> marks as regular text